# Zend frame work Database connection and configuration

Tags: zend-framework

I am very new to zend frame work , I want to do some updation work in one project that  already done by other programmers, now iam trying to setting up this project in my local server (I am using xamp), i have created the database in phpmyadmin, but while running this project i got the following error....

"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'numberfo_admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:144 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(832): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(902): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote(1257218565, NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\NFL_021\library\Utils\session_handling.php(16): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('last_login_date...', 1257218565) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\NFL_021\application\controllers\IndexController.php(16): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): IndexController->indexAction() #6 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction') #7 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Front.php(946 in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144"

Plsss any one help me to fix this error........

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either have incorrect permissions set up with MySql or you're trying to access the database using wrong credentials from Zend Framework.  Verify that you can log in to the database with the credentials you're trying to use (via phpMyAdmin). Also verify that in Zend Framework you're using the credentials that indeed have access to the database in question.

Comment: Thanks for yopur replay,

Now i have solved this issue ,Now the project is running in my local server but the all pages are styless , the CSS files are not taken, for correcting this issue which configuration i have to do or which file i have to edit?

Plss help meee

Comment: I would say the same thing as the answer to your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665504/zendframework-css-problem

Answer (score 0):

Set password for Mysql user (it my be «root» or some other).
Then edit Zend configuration file such as application.ini