# Zendframework CSS Problem

Tags: zend-framework

I am very to new to zend frame work , I am trying to set up a project (Done by other programmer) in my local server, i have setted up this project, but all pages are styless in my browser, ie the CSS files are not taken in phtml pages, For solving this issue which file I have ti Edit?

Plss Help me

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the directory structure that your app has adapted. However checkout if you have views/scripts directory then, again depending upon the directory style used, the header.phtml file (if exist) will have invalid link to css.

If you dont have header.phtml, then use any text-editor and search in your views directory with keyword 'css', and you will get to know the possible file name.

Comment: Thanks for your replay!!!!!
I am trying to run one zend framework project in my local server, the all CSS path specified in this project are correct, but the pages are styless and also the links are not wotking, my doubt is , need i make any changes in .httaccess file?

Plsss Help me

Comment: can you please share the directory structure of your application and the html (view source in browser) that displays css being linked?
<link..src="...your.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

Global css files I would add in the bootstrap file and any styles that relate to a page I would add in the relevant controller action for example...

**global styles in bootstrap file**

```
protected function _initView()
    {
        $this->view = new Zend_View();
        $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/global.css');
    }
```

**or in a specific controller action**

```
public function myPageAction()
{
   $view = $this->view;
   $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/myPageStyles.css');

}
```